# When is using runNow() allowed in scalajs-react and why?

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-react

The `runNow` method [here](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/0ed2fa7057078e09523aafe9327c96dd5bbd6984/core/src/main/scala/japgolly/scalajs/react/Callback.scala#L326) has the documentation:

```
  /**
   * Executes this callback, on the current thread, right now, blocking until complete.
   *
   * In most cases, this type is passed to scalajs-react such that you don't need to call this method yourself.
   *
   * Exceptions will not be caught. Use [[attempt]] to catch thrown exceptions.
   */
```

This is a little bit vague and leads to four questions:

1. when I am not supposed to call `runNow()` ? why ?
2. is it so that the only situation when I should not (or don't have to) call `runNow()` is when I am using a Callback with `==>` or `-->` (as described [here](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/VDOM.md#event-handlers)) ?  (my guess that this is true) or is there any other situation when `runNow()` is called for me by the framework ?
3. when I am allowed to call `runNow()`? why ?
4. why not just use `runNow` all the time ? would that cause any problems ? if yes, what ?

My current understanding is that it is ok (and even needed) to call `runNow()` from a [scala-function that has been passed as a callback](https://github.com/jhegedus42/scalajs-react-playaround/blob/master/src/main/scala/Demo/SortableContainerDemo.scala#L52) to a wrapped native JS react component. For example [here](https://github.com/jhegedus42/scalajs-react-playaround/blob/9b4d69ce50a9ac5e89f07982b8f666d246f4df9d/src/main/scala/interop/wrappers/react_sortable_hoc/SortableContainer.scala#L54).

I am not sure however.

Can someone clarify when it is OK and when it is not OK to call `runNow()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide a more detailed answer tomorrow but first, have you read through the `Callback` docs? https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/CALLBACK.md

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the answer, actually it seems that docs have been updated since I last read them ! So I have read only the old version. Need to read the new one and see how that answers the question.

Comment: No worries. As the author, what I think is clear isn't so and it's a bit hard to know what's missing or confusing. Give me a shout if something's not making sense and/or feel free to PR any improvements.

Comment: Golly, Could you please comment on this question ? It comes up again. I cannot find the answer in the doc. What I really don't understand is who is executing a `Callback` ? In the doc's it  says : As is stressed above, "Callbacks are meant to be executed by React at a time and frequency of its choosing." When is this ? What does scala-js do with these callbacks ? How do they get executed in the end ?

Comment: I mean, what is the corresponding concept (to Callbacks) in plain react ? I cannot really find it here : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html Where do these Callbacks (in scalajs-react) come from ? Why do they even exist in scalajs-react ? In the react docs there is not much mention of callback - for example they cannot be found on the left side of the react document webpage). So why are they treated specially in scalajs-react (there is a long page of documentation dedicated to it : https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/CALLBACK.md )?

Comment: React has a concept of callbacks, it's just often implicit and hinted at in documentation like "don't call this at this point of time", "blah is only valid when blah". As React JS is untyped, scalajs-react is typed and so the callback concept and execution semantics separation is explicitly represented in Scala. Same story with Backends.